# Show that there exists no integer $x$ such that $3x$ is congruent to 5 (modulo 6)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

So far my approach was to rewrite the congruency to $5-3x=6t$ for some integer $t$. My problem is I get stuck in trying to show how $5-3x$ is never divisible by $6$.

Comment: Consider the equation mod $\,3.\ \ $

Comment: a number is divisible by 6 if and only if that number is divisible by 2 and 3. So try to show if $5-3x$ is divisible by 2 and 3. If it is not then $5-3x$ is not divisible by 6. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks this helps, i will try

Comment: thanks for all the quick responses!

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $$5-3x=6t\implies 5=3\cdot(x+2t)$$, but 5 is a prime number with a prime factor 3 and this is a contradiction

Comment: thanks that helps, i actually used your implication as 5=3x+6t and applied the euclidean algorithm theory to it.    because for the euclidean algorithm, the GCD of (3,6) is 3 and if 3 can not divide 5 then there can be no integers for x and t.  Thank again!

Comment: @Jared Yes or apply the "arithmetic fundamental theorem"

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$R: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}$$
be the function which returns the remainder when you divide $n$ by 6.

Then

$$\forall n, m \in \mathbb{N}: R(n \cdot m) = R(R(n) \cdot R(m))$$

and especially

\begin{align}
R(3x) &= R(R(3) \cdot R(x))\\
&= R(3 \cdot R(x))
\end{align}

Now go through all possibilities:

\begin{align}
R(x) = 0 &\Rightarrow R(3 \cdot 0) = 0\\
R(x) = 1 &\Rightarrow R(3 \cdot 1) = 3\\
R(x) = 2 &\Rightarrow R(3 \cdot 2) = 0\\
R(x) = 3 &\Rightarrow R(3 \cdot 3) = 3\\
R(x) = 4 &\Rightarrow R(3 \cdot 4) = R(12) = R(2 \cdot 6) = 0\\
R(x) = 5 &\Rightarrow R(3 \cdot 5) = R(15) = R(12 + 3) = 3\\
\end{align}